# AFNetworking HTTP Proxy

Tags: ios, proxy, afnetworking

I'm having some trouble with AFNetworking and HTTP Proxy settings. Since AFNetworking is built off of NSURLConnection, does it have in-built support for a HTTP Proxy added in the wifi settings of an iPad / iPhone? Or do I have to do something programmatically while building my URLs to support a proxy?

Thanks,
Teja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it seems like NSURLConnection / AFNetworking only supports HTTP Basic Authentication out of the box. If the proxy uses NTLM auth, setting the auth in the wifi settings works for Safari, but not with any other app. (Tested Foursquare, Facebook etc.). When you first launch Safari though, you get a pop-up asking you to enter username / password even though you've specified username / password in wifi settings on the iPad. After entering them here, everything works fine with Safari.

There are NSURLRequest delegate methods provided as a part of iOS5 that are supposed to get called when a proxy issues an authentication challenge. But these again were never getting called. Not sure if this is a buggy behavior or if I've set something up incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

Update for AFNetworking / iOS 7:  If you use the *session instead of the *requestoperation interface, you can configure an HTTP Proxy using [`[NSURLSessionConfiguration -connectionProxyDictionary]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLSessionConfiguration/).

Answer (score 0):

As it's built on `NSURLConnection`, it just works. You can try it easily by using [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/).